# how to test anonymous class object inside method

Tags: java, unit-testing, anonymous-class

I'm writing unit cases using testNg and Mockito.The problem, I'm facing is with the method given below:

```
public void publishRequest(final NotificationRequest request){

    MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {

        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Start of MessagePublisher publishRequest");
            }
            ObjectMessage msg = session.createObjectMessage();

            msg.setStringProperty(
                    "SELECTOR",
                    request.getAvailaibilityTier() + "-"
                            + request.getEsbReference());

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Message Selector=>"+msg.getStringProperty("SELECTOR"));
            }

            msg.setStringProperty(NotificationConstants.CACHE_KEY.name(),
                    request.getId());

            msg.setObject(request.getData());
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Publishing request -->" + request);
            }

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("End of MessagePublisher publishRequest");
            }
            return msg;
        }
    };
    producerTemplate.send(messageCreator);
}
```

While writing the unit case createMessage() method is not being called even if my test case creates the MessageCreater object. I want to include that also in my unit case to get the better coverage. Any Idea how to test inner class method?

Comment: What does your test look like? What do you want to assert?

Answer (score 5):

It could be argued that the anynomous inner class is an implementation detail of the `publishRequest` method. When doing unit testing, you'll get more robust tests by testing the contract of `publishRequest` rather than the internal implementation. As @vtheron suggested, to test your `MessageCreator`, you have to extract it to it's own class. But in addition to that, consider "injecting" a reference to your `MessageCreator` in your class as well. That way, you can test both your `publishRequest` and `MessageCreator` in isolation. Personally, I prefer to "inject" such dependencies in a constructor, but there are other ways to achieve the same. I would do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MessageCreator messageCreator;

    public MyClass(MessageCreator messageCreator) {
        this.messageCreator = messageCreator;
    }

    public void publishRequest(final NotificationRequest request) {
        producerTemplate.send(messageCreator);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply send a "Mock" `MessageCreator` to your class in a test:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testPublish() {
        MessageCreator mock = new MessageCreator() { // Mock impl (or use a mock library)};
        MyClass classToTest = new MyClass(mock);
        classToTest.publishRequest(notificationRequest);
        // Do assertions and verify
    }
}
```

It's still testing the internals of your `publishRequest` method (testing `void` methods tends to), but if you can formulate a contract like

> when a request is published, a message should be sent to a queue

rather than

> publishRequest should create a MessageCreator and create a message that is sent by the producer

at least you have a more abstract approach to writing the tests, which definetively will affect how you write tests in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the need to test the behavior of your anonymous class move it outside of the publishRequest method, make it either a top level class or a static class in the class containing your publishRequest method.